# Use OAuth Bearer tokens only for certain controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

Using OAuth to allow access to an web api. I have something like this (from various tutorials for example: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/):

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver kernel)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

}
```

In `Startup.cs`. But this turns on authorization globally for all my controllers. Is there a way to turn it on just for a single controller (or a handful of controllers or methods)?  I have custom authorization for other parts of the website and I could go in to them and just check if the credentials passed is a bearer token and just reject it, but I'm wondering if there isn't a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with Oauth lately and had a different scenario that I needed to [allowAnonymous] to certain controllers in the API while denying anonymous to the remainder of my project.

I don't know if this will help your situation or not but thought I would share just in case it was helpful.

adding the below to the Web.config of the API for each controller I needed to allowAnonymous for solved my scenario.

```
</system.codedom>
  <location path="api/controller">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [AllowAnonymous] decorator at controller level or inside any web method. For me it was not necessary to configure web.config as suggested by @Marshall

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyController : ApiController
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDetails(string name) {}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to allow anonymous to parts of the site. That wasn't the question. The question was to allow bearer in some parts and other authorization elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry, ok, then your answer is no, there's no more elgant solution :)